# Is this a good response to an email for interview request?

Tags: words, written-language

I just received an interview request written entirely in Japanese. But the email mentions to inform them if I have difficulty communicating in Japanese and is asking what would be good interview dates. I've written this basic starter response and plan to switch to English right after.

Do you think this is a good way to respond to the email? I only have one part of the name in Kanji, the other part is in English and I have a hard time telling if it's the first or last name. I also don't know the Kanji for it.

Thank you so much for any help on this, I really appreciate it.

The message so far:

様、

面接依頼でよろしくお願いします。

私は日本語が少し話せます。これのために英語は大丈夫ですか？

いただきありがとうございます。

Comment: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).

Comment: @istrasci Thank you for replying. Is it possible you know anywhere I may get a trustworthy translation? How would you recommend I approach this?

Comment: @StackMatch hinative might be an option: https://hinative.com/en-US

Answer (score 1):

That is completely wrong :)

様、← You must to add a name before 様, not just 様[sama]

面接依頼でよろしくお願いします。← You trying to say, something like "thank you for interview"? That is wrong too

私は日本語が少し話せます。← That is Ok.

これのために英語は大丈夫ですか？ ← That means "Because of it, can I use English?". It is strange: "I'm little bit speaking Japanese, because of it can I speak English?"

いただきありがとうございます。 ← Just wrong

```
{OPPONENT_NAME}様

お世話になっております。{YOUR_NAME}と申します。

ご連絡いただいて、どうもありがとうございます。

日本語は簡単な文書しかわかりませんので、
英語を使ってよろしいでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。
```

```
mister {OPPONENT_NAME}

untranslatable Japanese greeting. My name is {YOUR_NAME}.

Thank you for contact me.

I can understand just simple Japanese sentences, so
may I use English?

Something like "with best regards"
```

Comment: Hi rzlvmp, thank you for replying. When I was told I couldn't get a translation here I stopped checking. I just looked again and found your reply. Thank you so much for replying and helping me with this! Your work here is really appreciated and I wanted to say I'm grateful.